# Access to a function of subclass from an array of object of superclass

Tags: java

I have class `Carte` and `Croyant`, `DeuxEx` are subclass of `Carte`. In `Croyant` and `DeuxEx`, there are attributes `valueCroyant` or `valueDeuxEx` which just exists in each class. I create an array of `Object` of class `Carte`. How can I access to method `getValueCroyant()` or `getValueDeuxEx()` from object of this array.

```
Class Carte {
    private int id;
    public Carte(int id){
        this.id=id;
    }
}
Class Croyant extends Carte{
    private int valueCroyant;
    public Croyant(int id){
        super(id);
    }
    public int getValueCroyant(){
        return this.valueCroyant;
    }
}
Class DeuxEx extends Carte{
    private String valueDeuxEx;
    public DeuxEx(int id){
      super(id); 
    }
    public String getValueDeuxEx(){
       return this.ValueDeuxEx;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] agrs){
    ArrayList<Carte> array_carte = new ArrayList();
    Croyant cr1 = new Croyant(1);
    Croyant cr2 = new Croyant(2);
    DeuxEx de1= new DeuxEx(3);
    DeuxEx de2 = new DeuxEx(4);
    array_carte.add(cr1);
    array_carte.add(cr2);
    array_carte.add(de1);
    array_carte.add(de2);
    for(Carte c:array_carte){
       if(c instanceof Croyant){
           System.out.println(c.getValueCroyant()); 
        }else{
           System.out.println(c.getValueDeuxEx()); 
        }
    }
}
```

I want to do a for loop like this, but it doesn't work. Can somebody help me please!

Comment: That code won't even compile. Also by "boucle" you probably mean "loop". Google and google translate are your friends here.

Comment: which class is your `main()` a part of here, or are you simply trying to execute this code?

Answer (score 0):

c.getValueCroyant() won't compile because its type is Carte which is the superclass.
Even if it is not elegant, to call this method, using instanceOf is fine but you have also to cast to Croyant

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do hints strongly at a problem with your design.  The suggestion in another answer of testing with `instanceof` and casting would work, but it's very anti-OO.  Basically, that kind of solution circumvents polymorphism.

I see that `valueCroyant` is an `int` while `valueDeuxEx` is a `String`.  The best solution would be to rethink your design so these values are either the same type or implement some common interface.  Then move the value and the getter to the common superclass `Carte`.  If it's impossible to represent both values using the same type, then give `Carte` an abstract method that is meant to do something with the value, and implement it differently in each subclass.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should cast. The code snippet shown by you won't compile.

Something like this:

```
for(Carte c:array_carte){
       if(c instanceof Croyant){
           System.out.println(((Croyant)c).getValueCroyant()); 
        }else if(c instanceof DeuxEx){
           System.out.println(((DeuxEx)c).getValueDeuxEx()); 
        }
    }
```

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40755083/using-an-interface-in-an-arraylist/40755340#40755340).

Comment: please elaborate the answer according to the OPs question or mark duplicate if this looks similar to some other link

Comment: @nullpointer Thanks. I edited to show the type casting I was referring to.

Comment: (Croyant)c works well.That what i find. thank you so much ^^