# Using an Interface in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, interface

Okay so I have an Interface and 2 classes that implement it. The only problem is both classes have methods within them that aren't listed in the interface. I have a test class that uses an ArrayList of the interface type:

```
ArrayList<Company> employees = new ArrayList<Company>();
```

The program is designed to allow creation of two seperate classes of employees

```
public class Salaried implements Company
```

and

```
public class Hourly implements Company
```

and allow certain methods to be used with them. The two classes both implement the interface, but also have additional methods unique to themselves.

In the test class, I'm trying to use the arrayList to store the different employees that are created, so that their methods can be used later. However the program won't compile as I use methods that aren't in the interface when creating the employees and it won't let me use those methods.

How should I go about fixing this? Is it a mistake within the interface or within the classes themselves?

Comment: you can use `default` method if java 8

Comment: How do you expect to use a method if you don't know which class you're referring to?

Comment: @shmosel I do know which class i'm referring to. What my question is asking is how to put two classes that implement a common interface into a singular arrayList if they both need to be accessed from the list in order to use methods that aren't included in the interface.

Comment: If you know which class it is, use a list of the class instead of the interface.

Comment: @shmosel There are two different classes that need to go into the same arrayList. They share a common interface, so I made an arrayList of the interface type. However both classes use methods that aren't included in the interface, so when I try to use those methods from the arraylist, it doesn;t work and says it can't recognize the method as it isn't part of the interface. Example: employees.get(0).setPay(_annualSalary); Causes the error

Comment: So back to my question: why do you think you would be able to call a method on an object that may or may not have the method in question?

Comment: This indicates a problem with your design. Generally speaking, you should operate at the level where you have a common interface. Providing some specific examples might help us suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you should cast. Try type type casting to call implementation specific methods.

```
ArrayList<Company> companies = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Company c : companies) {
        if (c instanceof Salaried) {
            Salaried s = (Salaried) c;
            //call salaried methods
        } else if (c instanceof Hourly) {
            Hourly h = (Hourly) c;
            //call hourly methods
        } else {
            throw new AssertionError("Unknown subtype of Company found.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will work, but it is a nasty code smell, and there is usually a cleaner way to handle the issue.

Comment: @chrylis Agreed. I would always prefer to use the super type. But this answer is specifically to help the OP.

Answer (score 0):

> However the program won't compile as I use methods that aren't in the interface when creating the employees and it won't let me use those methods.

I'm not sure what you mean by this. If you instantiate a variable of type `Salaried`, you can call your methods specific to the `Salaried` class. This is also true for `Hourly`. From there, you can add to your `ArrayList` since both `Salaried` and `Hourly` implements `Company`.

Comment: This is the part that causes the error:                      `employees.add(new Salaried());
System.out.println("Please enter employee name: ");
String _name = in.nextLine();          employees.get(0).setName(_name);
System.out.println("Please enter the social security number: ");      String _ssn = in.nextLine();
employees.get(0).setSsn(_ssn);
System.out.println("Please enter the annual pay: ");
double _annualSalary = in.nextDouble();
employees.get(0).setPay(_annualSalary);
System.out.println("Salaried Employee has been created.");` - It does set name and set ssn fine, but not set pay

Comment: If you want to continue using an `ArrayList` of `Company`, then instantiate a `Salaried` employee first, set its properties, and then add to the `ArrayList`.